# Not showing any error messages but there is no data in BigQuery with PHP

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I tried to insert data into BigQuery in PHP but there is no data after running code without any errors. I referred to the Google documentation. If there is any mistakes on my code , I'd like to get it checked. Anybody has any ideas ??

```
<?php
    require "composer_project/vendor/autoload.php";
    use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
    $company_name = "";
    $sender_name = "";
    $phone_number = "";
    $mail_address = "";
    $content = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        if (!empty($_POST['company-name']) && !empty($_POST['sender-name']) && !empty($_POST['phone-number'])
        && !empty($_POST["mail-address"]) && !empty($_POST["content"])) {
            $company_name = $_POST['company-name'];
            $sender_name = $_POST['sender-name']; 
            $phone_number = $_POST['phone-number']; 
            $email_address = $_POST['email-address']; 
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            
            $project_id = 'test';
            $dataset_id = 'test';
            $table_id = 'test';
            $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
                'projectId' => $project_id,
            ]);
            $data = [
                'company_name' => $company_name,
                'sender_name' => $sender_name,
                'phone_number' => $phone_number,
                'email_address' => $email_address,
                'content' => $content
            ];
            $dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($dataset_id);
            $table = $dataset->table($table_id);
            $insertResponse = $table->insertRows([
                ['data' => $data]
            ]);
            if ($insertResponse->isSuccessful()) {
                print('Data streamed into BigQuery successfully' . PHP_EOL);
            } else {
                foreach ($insertResponse->failedRows() as $row) {
                    foreach ($row['errors'] as $error) {
                        printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error['reason'], $error['message']);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $err = "There is blank box";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did this line show `print('Data streamed into BigQuery successfully' . PHP_EOL);`?

Comment: What output do you get? Most paths (not all) throught this code produce something

Comment: No, it didn't show any messages at all and after then no data in BQ . But this part , printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error['reason'], $error['message']); showed error message with some fault on my code but I've already fixed it and now there is no error .

Comment: Then it would seem that the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {` is failing, so either you have a REQUEST_METHOD that is not `POST` or maybe try `==` instead of `===`

Comment: Sorry . That's just my carelessness. I used wrong name , !empty($_POST["mail-address"]) is not correct . It should be email_address . I missed "e" .

Answer (score 0):

My typo caused this problem . I used wrong name , `!empty($_POST["mail-address"])` is not correct . It should be email_address . I missed "e"